# What is the Intent that needs to be filtered to show a call log

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an application that has an activity that acts a s a call log, I want the user to be able to decide whether to use the stock android one or use ours. I can't seem to find which intent filter to set up for my activity in the manifest such that our app is listed in the chooser after a call is made and so that it can be set as a default if they wish.

Answer (score 0):

Set `<data>` mimeType to `vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls`

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
<data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/calls" />
```

I know this will prompt the user with a chooser after an outgoing call is terminated.

Comment: this doesnt seem to cause the chooser to show up at hangup, it actually didnt prompt any kind of behavior difference. Was I meant to do anything other than add that action and categories to the activity in the manifest?

Comment: At first I thought I was wrong, but this does actually work. It only works when an outgoing call is terminated and not an incoming call.

Comment: So after leaving the code on my phone for a little while I was noticing this working sometimes. It wasn't restricted to outgoing calls only though. It seems almost sporadic. Sometimes the chooser comes up (about 40%) of the time.

What makes you think that its only outgoing calls? and if so, is there a way to pop a chooser for incoming calls?

Comment: The IDE shows an error/warning: "Missing URL" . Seems something is missing, no?